# ORACLE Query to find value in other table based on dates

Tags: oracle, date, range, between

I have two tables, Table A has an ID and an Event Date and Table B has an ID, a Description and an Event Date.
Not all IDs in Table A appear in Table B and some IDs appear multiple times in Table B with different Descriptions for each event.
The Description in Table B is an attribute that can change over time, the Event date in Table B is the date that a given ID's Description changes from its default value (kept in another table) to the new value.
I want to find the Description in Table B that matches the Event Date in Table A so, for example

[Table Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrtnH.jpg)

A1234 would return Green and A4567 would return Null

I can't create tables here so I need to be able to this with a query.

Comment: Can you show us your query? What did you do the get the result?

Answer (score 0):

You can left join tables like:

```
select a.ID , b1.DESCRIPTION 
from TABLE_A a
left join TABLE_B b1 on a.ID = b1.id and a.EVENT_DATE > b1.EVENT_DATE
left join TABLE_B b2 on a.ID = b2.id and b1.EVENT_DATE < b2.EVENT_DATE and a.EVENT_DATE > b2.EVENT_DATE
where b1.id is null or b2.EVENT_DATE is null;
```

Comment: Thanks - and sorry about the question formatting, the sampel tables look fine in editing mode but are garbelled when posted... I have replaced it with a pic which doesn't seem to be showing?  Anyway I can't do a simple join on dates as the date in Table B is the date the Description changed, I need to take the date of an Event in Table A and find which description was current in Table B but all Table B has is the date(s) of the change

Answer (score 0):

This query will select last description from before the event:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT tabA.id, tabA.event_date, tabB.description,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tabB.id ORDER BY tabB.event_date DESC) rn
  FROM Table_A tabA 
  LEFT JOIN Table_B tabB ON tabA.id = tabB.id AND tabB.event_date <= tabA.event_date
) WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and to Aleksej below - I think both of these are in the right area but they are not giving me the results I expected - I think I need to reflect on this some more and will post back when I have figured it out (either making these suggestions work or something else)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your need, this could be a way:

```
select a.id, description
from tableA A
        left join 
         (select id,
                 description,
                 event_date from_date,
                 lead(event_date) over (partition by id order by event_date) -1 as to_date
          from tableB
         ) B
         on (A.id = B.id and a.event_date between b.from_date and b.to_date)
```

The idea here is to evaluate, for each row in `tableB` the range of dates for which that row, and its description, is valid; given this, a simple join should do the job.